# Calling Two OnLoad Functions Stops Other From Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onload

I'm a little confused here, I have two javascript files, one changes the background colour of the header when the user types a colour in a field and the other creates a random number generator and chooses an image based on the number chosen.

So I have to use `<body onload="setPreferenceColor();">` in the HTML` when setting the colour and since the RNG uses window.onload too I see that there is a clash which I do not know how to rectify.

If I remove the RNG script src, the header background colour changes fine but not when I place it back in.

Here is the background colour change javascript code

```
//Variables
//var myForm = document.getElementById('form')
var bgcolor = document.getElementById('bgcolor1') //places bgcolor1 field from HTML into variable 
//var font = document.getElementById('font1')
var header = document.getElementById('header')

bgcolor.addEventListener('input', updateStorage); //Adds eventlistener to listen to input in bgcolour field then call method
//font.addEventListener('input', updateStorage)

window.onload = function init(){ //When window has loaded execute this method
    var g = localStorage.getItem('fontsize');
    document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = g;
    setPreferenceColor(); //Call method
}

function notfont(size) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.fontSize = size; //place in variable
    localStorage.setItem('fontsize',size); //set fontsize into variable
}

function updateStorage (){
    localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', bgcolor.value); //After obtaining the input from eventlistener store bgcolor.value
    //localStorage.setItem('font', font.value);
    setPreferenceColor(); 
}

function setPreferenceColor(){
    var myColor = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor') //variable that retrieves value from bgcolor 
    var fontsize =localStorage.getItem('fontsize')
    header.style.backgroundColor = myColor; //style background colour by calling variable
    header.style.fontSize = fontsize;
}
```

Here is the RNG change javascript code

```
window.onload = choosePic; // Run Function When Website Runs
//Variables
var advertArray = new Array("./images/service2.png","./images/service3.png","./images/service4.png"); //Array of 3 Images

var lastViewedImage = localStorage.getItem('lastViewedImage');

function choosePic() {
    randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * advertArray.length)); 
    //Random Number Generator based on the number of pictures in array

    if (lastViewedImage == randomNum) {
        //advertArray.splice(lastViewedImage, 1)    
    }
    document.getElementById("advert").src = advertArray[randomNum]; //Random Number with image is set in HTML
    localStorage.setItem('lastViewedImage', randomNum);  //Set variable in localstorage with value of RNG
}
```

Comment: Use `window.addEventListener("load", function(){`…`})` (or `window.addEventListener("load", choosePic)`) instead of `window.onload = function(){`…`}`.

Comment: AHA! Thank you so much, any chance you can tell me why this managed to work and what I was doing wrong?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “this managed to work”. I don’t know what other version of your code you’re referring to. If you mean the `<body>` `onload` attribute: the `<body>` is `document.body`, which is different from `window`.

Comment: I'm just wondering how the code you gave me fixed my problem

Comment: Oh, that’s just because `window.onload = `…`;` _assigns_ a function to `window.onload`. If you assign another function you reassign `window.onload`, meaning you replace the previous function by a new function. It’s just like `var a = 2; var a = 4;`. At the end, `a` isn’t 2 anymore, it’s just 4. `addEventListener` handles functions more intelligently by appending new functions instead of replacing them.